# Degrees of freedom of a metric up to coordinate changes (precise formulation)

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, jet-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold. I have heard that a Riemannian metric on $M$, depends locally on $ n(n+1) / 2 - n = n(n-1) /2$ "independent" functions *up to coordinate changes*.

I can roughly see the intuition for that: The symmetric matrix $g_{ij}
$ depends on $n(n+1) / 2$ functions, but you can "change the coordinates" which loses $n$ degrees of freedom.

> Is there a precise formulation of this statement? Given an arbitrary metric, can you  really specify $n$ out of the $ n(n+1)/2$ $g_{ij}$ functions as you wish? How can we see it's impossible specify more than $n$?

I heard that **Cartan** proved something like this, using the language of jets. 
(Something about the dimension of the space of $k$-jets of metrics modulu diffeomorphisms).

Maybe there are other references; any pointer in the right direction is welcomed.

This question was supposedly answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/612369/104576), but I find the answer there to be too vague. I am looking for a precise statement.

Comment: This might be related to the fact that the sectional curvature completely determines the Riemann curvature, and the sectional planes (bivectors) have $n(n-1)/2$ degrees of freedom. But the curvature does not determine the metric... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973957/non-isometric-surfaces-with-equal-curvature